# Is there any need for more server-side Form validation than when declaring arguments?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

In my CFCs that handle form submissions, I am doing validation at the start of the function by declaring what arguments are required and what type they should be. As such:

```
<cfarugment name="forename" type="string" required="true"/>
```

What I am also currently doing is checking the value when inserting into the database. As such:

```
INSERT INTO Person (Forename)
VALUES
(
<cfif structKeyExists(ARGUMENTS, 'Forename') AND Len(Trim(ARGUMENTS.Forename)) GT 0>
<cfqueryparam value="#ARGUMENTS.Forename#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar">
<cfelse>
NULL
</cfif>
);
```

Is there any need to check that the argument value exists and its length when its already been declared that its a required value?

Comment: Required doesn't enforce a length. You can pass in an empty value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to

1. run the data through an [anti-Samy](https://code.google.com/p/owaspantisamy/downloads/list) filter, which will strip out any invalid HTML entities and protect against [Cross-site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_site_scripting) attacks
2. verify that the form request is coming from your server using a [Cross-Site Request Forgery token](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29)

and that's just off the top of my head.

Comment: Over and above that, I do not think input valuation belongs in the same function start which writes to the database.  Split this lot into two separate processes.

Comment: @AdamCameron how else would I insert a NULL value into the database?

Comment: cfqueryparam has a null attribute.

Comment: @volumeone I was referring to all the other measures mentioned in this answer: you have a bunch more validation you *should* be doing over and above a length-check. Once you're validated and ready to store the data, call a method to store it. Within that, it's still fine to existence-check or length-check a value to determine whether it needs inclusion in your SQL statement.